# Inner Join with Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

Having trouble getting this inner join to work, I know I'm doing this wrong, but can't figure out how to do it right.

I'm trying to select every column from the `user_meta` table, and add the `name` column from the `users` table to the resulting array. I'm using the key `username`, which cascades on both tables as the key.

I'm then trying to return it as an object to the calling function.

This is what I've got :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM user_meta
        INNER JOIN name as name FROM users 
        WHERE username = :username';

$db = static::getDB();
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_called_class());

$stmt->execute();

return $stmt->fetch();
```

But I'm getting a 1064 back so my syntax is obviously wrong.

*** EDIT ***

I've made some progress, but it's not ideal. Basically I'm now returning everything from both tables by using LEFT JOIN. But I only want to LEFT JOIN the `name` column from the `users` table.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM user_meta
        LEFT JOIN users
        ON user_meta.username = users.username';
```

Comment: You define which table to join, but not which columns to join on. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: `'SELECT * FROM user_meta
        INNER JOIN users ON users.column = user_meta.column
        WHERE username = :username'`

Comment: Tried that, now getting this `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'username' in where clause is ambiguous'`

Answer (score 0):

`tb1` and `tb2` represents the 2 table, its like saving on a variable.

```
SELECT tb1.*, tb2.name  
FROM user_meta tb1
INNER JOIN users tb2
ON tb1.username = tb2.username
WHERE tb1.username = :username
```

`tb1` calls every column in `meta_users` while `tb2` only call the name from `user`.

Comment: Sorry bro I can't work out what I'm meant to put where? Can you be a bit more descriptive please or use the vars I've got so I can see how you are doing it?

Comment: Thanks, but no joy. Now I get `Base table or view not found`

Comment: aaay wait is the second table named `users` instead of `user`

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it!

LEFT JOIN was the order of the day, not INNER JOIN.

In case anybody else gets stumped with something similar :

First select everything from the user_meta table `user_meta.*` then select the name column from the users table `users.name`.

The ON method is where you add your comparison key between the two separate tables, in my case both columns are called the same thing in each table `username`.

```
$sql = 'SELECT user_meta.*, users.name
        FROM user_meta
        LEFT JOIN users
        ON user_meta.username = users.username
        WHERE user_meta.username = :username';
```